# Automated Testing Jobs

Tags: automation, testing

We have multiple environments close to 7 for an application that has UI and also integration server that accepts SOAP xmls.

Its hard to maintain the environment integrity when many people working, developing, testing on these servers. Almost every 2nd day one or the other environment has issue and lot of effort and time goes in fixing that.

What we are looking for is an automated testing tool that has a capability to run/schedule test cases both UI based (like macros) and XML based. Lets say this tool runs the test cases every morning on each of the environment and sends out an email report of the output/results.

Based on your experience which tool fits best to our requirement. Please suggest.

Regards,
Viv

Answer (score 3):

I see a mismatch between the problem you describe and the solution you're asking for.  Your problem seems to be managing your environments.  You seem to think automated testing is the answer.

But why not automate managing your environments to prevent the manual effort that goes into fixing them?

It's very important to reset test environments to a known good state before running automated tests.  Without a reset, it takes effort to figure out if a test failure is due to code changes or environment changes.  It's about the same effort as manually fixing the environment in my experience.

There are many approaches for creating or resetting test environments.  Probably it's a too broad question and a matter of opinion.

Once you have a repeatable way to provide a known good test environment, there are many tools for automating regular test runs and emailing results.  Probably it's a too broad question and a matter of opinion.

Comment: See also https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-are-the-pro-and-cons-of-snowflakes-servers-phoenix-servers-and-immutable-s

Comment: Actually automated testing will serve couple of purpose. First to check the sanity of environments and second performing a regression testing. Automate environment managment I feel would be more complex as our application involves 4 different products.

Comment: No amount of automation will help you if you have devs and testing on the same machine.  Surely some of those VMs could be reserved for testing alone?